# Postgresql GROUB BY combination

Tags: postgresql, group-by

Hi I have a problem with the group by clause if I have combinations between,

This is a part from my table with combinations:

```
CREATE TABLE sampleTable 
    (
     id serial primary key, 
     sat1 varchar(3), 
     sat2 varchar(3)
    );

INSERT INTO sampleTable
(sat1, sat2)
VALUES
('LE7','LE7'),
('LE8','LE7'),
('LE7','LE7'),
('LE7','LC8'),
('LE7','LE8'),
('LE8','LE7'),
...
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/63104/2

I search the count of combinations, but for me the combination sat1,sat2 is the same like sat2,sat1.

My (wrong) SQL-Code:

```
select sat1, sat2, count(*) from sampleTable group by sat1, sat2 order by sat1
```

and the result:

```
    sat1    sat2    count
1   LC8     LC8     27
2   LC8     LE7     17
3   LE7     LE7     200
4   LE7     LC8     22
5   LM1     LM2     2
6   LM1     LM1     12
7   LM2     LM2     6
8   LM2     LM1     3
```

but it should by:

```
    sat1    sat2    count
1   LC8     LC8     27
2   LC8     LE7     39  (17+22 / line 2 & 4)
3   LE7     LE7     200
4   LM1     LM2     5   (2+3 / line 5 & 8)
5   LM1     LM1     12
6   LM2     LM2     6
```

Has anyone a SQL-Code which solved my question?
Thanks for Help!!

Comment: Line 2 says for column1 = LC8 AND column2 = LE7 COUNT = 17
While line 4 says for column1 = LE7 AND column2 = LC8 COUNT = 22
It's not the same!

Comment: I now what the groub by-clause take, therefore I search a SQL-Code which solve my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LEAST() and GREATEST() to "simplify" the 2 grouping columns:

**Query 1**:

```
select least(sat1, sat2), greatest(sat1, sat2), count(*) 
from sampleTable 
group by least(sat1, sat2), greatest(sat1, sat2)
order by least(sat1, sat2)
```

**[Results][2]**:

```
| least | greatest | count |
|-------|----------|-------|
|   LC8 |      LC8 |    27 |
|   LC8 |      LE7 |    39 |
|   LE7 |      LE7 |   200 |
|   LM1 |      LM1 |    12 |
|   LM1 |      LM2 |     5 |
|   LM2 |      LM2 |     6 |
```

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/63104/4)